# How to configure a lab environment in CentOS VMware virtual machine for RHCE

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, virtualbox, centos, vmware

I want to configure 3 servers in VMware and I am a beginner with less knowledge in this field

Host system is a Windows 10 ip (192.168.40.40) (ip configuration is dynamic)

1. server1.example.com IP (192.168.40.10) Same subnet (bridged connection through my wifi adapter) possible to connect to internet (ping to google is successful)
2. tester1.example.com IP (192.168.40.20) Same subnet (bridged connection through my wifi adapter) possible to connect to internet (ping to google is successful)
3. outsider.example.org IP (192.168.100.30) Different subnet.

I have configured the first two using a bridged connection in VMware using Default DHCP and DNS ie 192.168..40.1 assigned by the system. DHCP and IP assignment is dynamic in my host system.

Configured a static IP in 192.168.40.10 and 192.168.40.20 using the below mentioned steps.

1. A new Ethernet connection  eth0 is created command used:

   ```
   nmcli connection add type ethernet con-name eth0 ifname ens33 ipv4.addresses 192.168.40.10/24 ipv4.dns 192.168.40.1 ipv4.gateway 192.168.40.1 ipv4.method manual
   nmcli device connect ens33; nmcli connection down eth0; nmcli connection up eth0
   ```

If i want to configure the third system with an IP 192.168.100.30 in vmware CentOS guest and to ping the other two CentOS system and google what should i do. Which network configuration is should chose in vmware hostonly, NAT, Bridged and what configuration should i do in my host and guest without disturbing the other two configuration. With the help of internet and other source i have configured the 2 please guide me to configure the 3rd server.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need a router to route between the two isolated networks.  (Keep in mind, the router doesn't need to be a physical router.  There are many guides on how to build linux-based routers that would do the trick without any problems)

Comment: Would an IP forwarding form the third would work. If i do, can i connect to the internet.

Comment: Is there any reference for building a linux based router in vmware

Comment: IP forwarding in vmware workstation wouldn't work.  It forwards connectivity out to the Internet, but does not allow a VM in one network to talk to another network.  Plus... NATs get ugly quick.

As for building a router... yes.  Tons of examples of how-to-build-a-router-in-linux can be found on google.  Pick one.

Comment: I configured the third with NAT option in network connectivity and it started working fine and if i need to  build a router in linux it should be a Virtual machine or it should be a host. Please advise

Comment: issue still exist... able to connect to other system from guest and vice versa. If I am using a dynamic ip assignment. If I configure a static ip assignment outgoing connection from guest to other system is possible but incoming connection from other system to guest is not working